# Why does only one column are being updated in my table database?

Tags: c#

I am updating MyAccount however only one column[Password] is being updated. Below is my code. Please help thanks.

```
private string connstr =
        System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
private SqlConnection conn;
private SqlCommand cmd;

conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AdminUsers Set Name=@Name, UserName=@UserName,  
                      Address=@Address, Phone=@Phone, Email=@Email, Password=@Password
                     Where AdminUserID=@AdminUserID", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminUserID", lblAdminMyAcctID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtAdminMyAcctName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtAdminMyAcctUserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAdminMyAcctAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtAdminMyAcctPhone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtAdminMyAcctEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtAdminMyAcctNewPassword.Text);

conn.Open();
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{

}
conn.Close();

Here are my Data at my Database

ID  Name    UserName    Address     Phone            Email                 UserType Branch      Status  Password
4   Default Admin       Auckland    64 123 45678910  admin@admin.com        Admin       Main        True    admin
6   Groomer Groomer2    Main        0221210801       groomer2@groomer.com   Groomer     Glen Ines   True    groomer3
7   Groomer Groomer1    Main        0221210800       groomer1@groomer.com   Groomer     Duniden     True    groomer1
```

Is there any wrong in my database?

Comment: code looks fine.can you include the sample data you entered and the data that was already there in AdminUsers table for any AdminUserID in the question?

Comment: As a complete aside, consider using the `using` statement for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.  Both of them implement the `IDisposable` interface and may take advantage of it.  Just a thought -- in the end, it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide us more information about the table structure? i could think of the Upper and Lower case of the column, what OS did you use the database on?

based on my experience , in Linux we should notice that upper and lower case affect the code, while on windows it doesn't (usually i code all with caps)

EDIT :

shouldn't it be =

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AdminUsers Set Name=@Name, UserName=@UserName,  
                  Address=@Address, Phone=@Phone, Email=@Email, Password=@Password
                 Where ID=@AdminUserID", conn);
```

i didn't see any AdminUserID column there